# Attribute contents extracion

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, attributes

I'm trying to simplify code for extracting data from property attribute.

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class NameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ColumnAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Attribute contents extraction code ( null-checks removed ):

```
public static string GetName<T>(string propName)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
    var nameAttribute = (NameAttribute)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NameAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
    return nameAttribute.Name;
}
```

Sample class:

```
class TestClass
{
    [Column("SomeName")]
    public object NamedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Call sample:

```
var name = GetName<TestClass>(nameof(TestClass.NamedProperty))
```

Is it any way to rewrite attribute contents extraction method to simplify/shorten its call. It's too inconvenient for me due to its length.

Something like [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) would be great but i found nothing.

Comment: It looks ok for me

Comment: I'm looking fow way to interpolate it into strings, 2..5 calls per string, but current call syntax is too long for it

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is already pretty short. The only redundant information is the class name, everything else is *needed*, it won't get much shorter. You could have a shorter syntax n your call as demonstrated below, where you remove the redundancy of the class name. However, that comes at the cost or a more complex implementation. It's up to you to decide if that's worth it:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Reflection;

    static class Program
    {
        // your old method:
        public static string GetName<T>(string propName)
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);

            var nameAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(NameAttribute)) as NameAttribute;

            return nameAttribute.Name;
        }

        // new syntax method. Still calls your old method under the hood.
        public static string GetName<TClass, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> action)
        {
            MemberExpression expression = action.Body as MemberExpression;
            return GetName<TClass>(expression.Member.Name);
        }
        
        static void Main()
        {
            // you had to type "TestClass" twice
            var name = GetName<TestClass>(nameof(TestClass.NamedProperty));

            // slightly less intuitive, but no redundant information anymore
            var name2 = GetName((TestClass x) => x.NamedProperty);

            Console.WriteLine(name);
            Console.WriteLine(name2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    class NameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public NameAttribute(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
    
    class TestClass
    {
        [Name("SomeName")]
        public object NamedProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output is the same:

> SomeName
>
> SomeName